# Generate a specific designed PDF from basic HTML input

Tags: python, html, forms

I want to generate a PDF with a specific background from three simple input-fields.

A title, a message and a signature as shown in the picture below.

[Example of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihIUm.png)

I have some experience with creating web-sites with Python Flask, but I struggle with how to tackle this challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a h1 containing the title, a h2 containing the message and a bottom text with some css

```
.bottom{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

put the background-image tag on the body to have your own custom image

it would be something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bottom{
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('mypicture.png'); text-align: center">

<h1>my title</h1>
<h2>my subtitle</h2>
<h2 class="bottom">bottom text</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found this link on codepen, https://codepen.io/richsale/pen/wvwjgvv
It is pretty close to what I want, but I don't know how to implement it on a website.

Comment: just add all the elements together in the same file with a script tag. changing some things in that code will look very similar to what its in there.